# I want my selectEnhenced form to show a searched name with its type next to it as a hint

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this form - for example a form for a new city - with some different selects and inputs. In one of them a user have to choose a commune - a commune for that particular city.

Before, on the select list, there was only a name of a commune, without the type - everything worked perfectly - but then I realised that to choose the right commune, the user need to know it's type too.

What I'm trying to make is something like this: when a user will type a name of a commune, it will show a list of available communes - the name of the commune with the type of that commune next to it:

[image: see the pic]

I tried to:

- change my model - in many different ways - for example by creating a new function that would contain two others;
- modify ajax - make something similar as in return?

But nothing works. In general I get a 500 server error because I want to put two "names" in one select. Is it possible to make it work the way I want?

Here are examples of my code:

- **FormTrait:**

  ```
            $form->selectEnhanced('commune_id', trans('dict.commune'))
                ->options(function ($id) {
                    $id = $id ? $id : old('commune_id');
                    if ($id) {
                        $commune = Commune::find($id);
                        return [$commune->id => $commune->communetranslation->name . ' (' . $commune->communetypetranslation->name . ')'];
                    }
                })
                ->ajax('/' . config('admin.route.prefix') . '/api/communes', 'id', 'communetranslation.name')
                ->loadParent('district_id', '/' . config('admin.route.prefix') . '/api/districts');
  ```
- **Model:**

  ```
   public function communetranslation()
   {
    return $this->getRelationDefinition($this->hasOne(CommuneTranslation::class, 'commune_id', 'commune_id'), 'commune_translations', 'commune_id');
   }

   public function communetypetranslation()
   {
    return $this->getRelationDefinition($this->hasOne('App\Models\CommuneTypeTranslation', 'commune_type_id', 'id'), 'commune_type_translations', 'commune_type_id');
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not my solution - it's my colleague that came up with it. I decided to put it here as it might be helpful for others who are facing same problem as me.

So in the end the first idea was a good one. Almost. Instead of combining two functions we created a new one which contains same information as the two others together. We just needed to use *first()* in it. Also I didn't use the correct syntaxes so obviously it didn't work out. Anyway, It should look like this:

```
public function getCommunenamenandtype() {
    return "{$this->communetranslation()->first()->name} ({$this->communetypetranslation()->first()->name})";
}
```

I got exactly the outcome I wanted (shown on the picture I have attached to my question). :-) Hope it will be helpful for You as well.